# How to use ng-click variables in my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which looks something like this

```
 <a href ng-click="metric='Distance'; metricshow=false;" >
 <a href ng-click="metric='Time'; metricshow=false;">
```

Now In my controller.

```
console.log($scope.metric);
    switch($scope.metric)
    {
        case 'Distance' : console.log('Distance');
        break;
        case 'Time' : console.log('Time');
        break;
    }
```

The console.log() gives me undefined. Why?

Comment: When is that `console.log` invoked? How are you declaring your controllers and their use at HTML?

Could you please put `{{metric}}` right behind the anchor tags

Comment: I am getting values at {{metric}}.  But not using $scope is what is causing the issue I believe

Comment: Again, please tell me where is that console.log placed

Comment: At the start of the controller.  And I get it,  the first time the program runs through it. $scope. Metric is undefined.  Could you tell me one thing like what is run first.  The html or the controller.  Or both are executed as they are encountered

Comment: Ive offered you an answer, telling some extra details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your controller first run, the $scope.metric variable was not created nor assigned to anything. You may also prefer not to use logic in your view, use functions instead.

Directive:

```
 <a href ng-click="setMetric('Distance')" >
 <a href ng-click="setMetric('Time')">

 <a href ng-click="getMetric()">
```

Now In your controller:

```
$scope.setMetric = function (type) {
  $scope.metric = type;
}

$scope.getMetric = function () {
  console.log($scope.metric);
}
```

[Working Plunker with some additions](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYFaLjSb1lSfpEQSd5IF?p=preview)

Comment: Woah...  This has the same approach as above and gives a much cleaner way to do it. +1 right away

Comment: Wow, thanks. I've discovered plnkr.co/ yesterday. I will make one for you. :)

Comment: Well that would be great.  It was tough call between fridjon and you.  For the answer.  You earned it.

Comment: Here is it: [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYFaLjSb1lSfpEQSd5IF?p=preview). I won't touch the answer, btw, the Plunker is a little more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned anything to the `$scope.metric` when the controller is created therefore it console logs undefined.

Now, if you had something like:

```
<a href ng-click="doSomething()" >
```

in your HTML and something like:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
    $scope.metric='Distance'; 
    $scope.metricshow=false;
    console.log($scope.metric);
}
```

in your controller, you would be responding to the ng-click.

Answer (score 2):

So, right as other answers tell, it's because that `console.log` is being executed right away.

I'd like to tell a few extra points:

1. It's better to use functions with `ng-click` instead of inline js code.
2. At HTML you can use `{{variable}}` for `$scope` interpolation.
3. There are `$watch` functions available.

#### `$scope` interpolation

So `$scope` is a *glue* between you controller and your JS code at controllers. You don't need to place `{{$scope.variable}}` because `$scope` becomes the global variable at markup.

This works great for app logic, useful when using `ng-repeat`, for example or just for fast debugging.

#### `$watch` functions

You could have, at your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('metric', function(newValue, oldValue){
  console.log("$scope.metric just changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
});
```

This is really useful for more sofisticated app logic, workflow and control. But you shouldn't do it for debugging.

---

About your question at last comment on what's being *executed* first, please check the docs on data binding and digest cycle.

Comment: $watch was something I missed completely. Great addition to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but according to your original code, I have created the similar situation.

```
 <a href ng-click="metric('Distance')" >
 <a href ng-click="metric('Time');">



 <script>
    $scope.metric = function(_parm){
        switch(_parm){
            case 'Distance': 
                console.log('Distance');
                $scope.metricshow = false;
                break;
            case 'Time' :
                console.log('Time');
                $scope.metricshow = false;
                break;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

For your reference, use ng-click to call function, THEN change the variables there. More readable, prettier on HTML side!