# How to show/hide different data on clicking different links in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to show different text on clicks over different button. Only one text should display at a time.

Eg. If I choose monthly it should display text Monthly only. And If i click on Quarterly It should display Quarterly only.

By default monthly should be loaded on page

```
<div ng-app="">
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <a href="" ng-click="month=true">Monthly</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="quarter=true">Quarterly</a>


 <div class="wrapper">
   <p ng-show="month || !quarter">Monthly</p>
   <p ng-show="quarter || !month">Quarterly</p>
</div>

</div>
```

See my code on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYqROR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to get rid of the logic on your view. Try to compute the logic of your app on your controller, so your view will be cleaner and easier to test. Try this instead:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <a href="" ng-click="setActive('montly')">Monthly</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="setActive('quarterly')">Quarterly</a>


  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-show="isActive('montly')">Monthly</p>
    <p ng-show="isActive('quarterly')">Quarterly</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And, on the controller:

```
$scope.setActive = function (name) {
  $scope.thing = name; }

$scope.isActive = function (name) {
  return ($scope.thing == name); } // Returns false if thing is different.
```

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555879/how-to-use-ng-click-variables-in-my-controller/33556068#33556068) and [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYFaLjSb1lSfpEQSd5IF?p=preview) is the resulting working Plunker. If you need, I can explain better.

Comment: "Must" is very strong. He really ought to, though.

Comment: Thanks guys!! Is there any way to do this using ng-if ?

Comment: Of course. You can just change nf-show to ng-if. I prefer to use ng-if, because the markup wont be on the DOM. ng-show will apply a 'hide' to the markup element.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it by setting a variable to either month or quarter and using that to evaluate the `ng-show`

```
<div ng-app="">
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <a href="" ng-click="type='month'">Monthly</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="type='quarter'">Quarterly</a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-show="type == 'month'">Monthly</p>
    <p ng-show="type == 'quarter'">Quarterly</p>
    </div>
</div>
```